# Solve_ivp not updating a parameter every iteration

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration

I have this function for solve_ivp, which solves a series of differential equations.
For every time step, the variable position [Pos] should be updated depending on a probability of it jumping. However, solve_ivp is not remembering the previous variable.

```
def jump_fun(t, Y, P, flux = 670):
    
    global Pos_list
    
    k1, k2 , k3, k4, k5, k6 , k , kay, q , K1, c5_tot, c6_tot, phi, Nc, V, qs, Cx, Ks, F, Cs0, flux, Pos, Pos_list = P
    
    
    c1, c2, c3, c4, c5 ,c6, c4ex1, c4ex2, Cs1, Cs2= Y.reshape([10,-1])
    
    #print(c1, c2, c3, c4, c5 ,c6, c4ex, Cs, Pos)
    print(f'Pos: {Pos}')
    # function heterogeneous_environment
    prob = heterogeneous_environment(Nc, flux, V, 10, 10)
    print(f'prob: {prob}')
    

#These arrays keep track of where the cells are
    R1 = np.where(Pos == 1, 1, 0 )
    R2 = np.where(Pos == 2, 1, 0 )
    

    # We need to know the external concentrations of each reactor

    rs1 = (Cx*qs*Cs1/ (Ks+Cs1))

    dCs1 = F/V + flux*Cs2/V - flux*Cs1/V - rs1    # Position of cell is reactor 1, C1 = Cs

    rs2 = (Cx*qs*Cs2/ (Ks+Cs2))

    dCs2 = flux*Cs1/V - flux*Cs2/V - rs2     # Position of cell is reactor 2, C2 = Cs

    j0 = rs1*R1 + rs2*R2
    

    jm1 = kay * (c4 - c4ex1)*R1
    
    jm2 = kay * (c4 - c4ex2)*R2

    dc1= j0 - (k1 * c1 * c6 * (1/( 1 + ((c6/K1 )**q))))

    dc2 = 2* k1 * c1 * c6 * (1/( 1 + ((c6/K1 )**q))) - k2 * c2 * (c5_tot - c5) - k6 *c2 *c5

    dc3 = k2 * c2 * (c5_tot - c5) - k3 * c3* (c6_tot - c6)

    dc4 =  k3 * c3* (c6_tot - c6) - k4 * c4 *c5 - (jm1*R1 + jm2*R2)

    dc5= k2 * c2 * (c5_tot - c5) - k4 * c4 *c5 - k6 *c2 *c5

    dc6 = -2 * k1 * c1 * c6 * (1/( 1 + ((c6/K1 )**q))) + 2 * k3 * c3* (c6_tot - c6) - k5 * c6

    cell1 = np.count_nonzero(R1 == 1)
    
    cell2 = np.count_nonzero(R2 == 1)

    
    dc4ex1= - k * c4ex1 + (phi / cell1) * np.sum(jm1) - (flux*c4ex1)/V + (flux*c4ex2)/V
    dc4ex2= - k * c4ex2 + (phi / cell2) * np.sum(jm2) + (flux*c4ex1)/V - (flux*c4ex2)/V

    #print('1')
    #print(Pos)
    #print('2')
    
    
    Pos = Pos + prob*R1
    Pos = Pos - prob*R2
    #print(Pos)
         
    Pos_list.append(Pos)
    #iterate through the Pos vector, if Pos =1 do the balances for reactor 1 and then if the probability says to change 
    #reactor, change the position of the cell. Same for POS=2
    #UPDATE THE MASS BALANCE FOR EACH REACTOR          

    return dc1, dc2, dc3, dc4, dc5 , dc6, dc4ex1, dc4ex2, dCs1, dCs2
```

I tried passing Pos as a return of the function, but it also didn't seem to work. Please help.

Comment: If the right-hand side of your system involves random variables, `solve_ivp` is the wrong function to use.  It sounds like you have a [stochastic process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_process) resulting in a system of [stochastic differential equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_differential_equation) (SDEs).  `solve_ivp` does not work for SDEs.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The right side of the derivatives does not depend on random variables. However, which derivatives are calculated do depend on a positional vector, which changes with a random vector. The derivatives are always the same.